# Is it secure to add a constant prefix string before encrypting data?

Tags: java, security, encryption

I wrote an encryption & decryption program in Java based on Serpent algorithm, which works fine. But I am wondering if it is secure to add a fixed prefix before data (6 bytes). I want to use this known string to compare the string before encryption with the string after decryption. Can anyone explain me if is a serious risk?

Thanks

For example:

```
public static final String INITIAL_FLAG = "qwerty";
```

crypto_serpent interface:

```
public String get_api_version();

//byte - byte
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException;
public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException;

//file - byte
public byte[] encrypt(File file, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException;
public byte[] decrypt(File file, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException;

//file - file
public boolean encrypt(File file_in, File file_out, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException;
public boolean decrypt(File file_in, File file_out, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException;

//byte - file
public boolean decrypt(byte[] data, File file_out, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException;
public boolean encrypt(byte[] data, File file_out, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException;

public int get_block_size();
```

Serpent implementation:

```
import gnu.crypto.cipher.Serpent;
import static busslina.crypto_serpent.Utils.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class API_impl implements API
{

private static final String API_VERSION = "1.1";

/**
 * Current api interfaz/implementation version
 * @return
 */
@Override
public String get_api_version()
{
    return API_VERSION;
}

public static final String INITIAL_FLAG = "QWERTY";
public static final int KEY_SIZE = 16;
public static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 16;

/**
 * TESTED. WORKS FINE
 * @param data
 * @param passwd
 * @return
 * @throws InvalidKeyException
 */
@Override
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException
{
    if(passwd.length() > KEY_SIZE)
        throw new InvalidKeyException("Password too long");

    Serpent s = new Serpent();

    //passwd (we need key to encrypt)
    byte[] passwd_byte = Utils.string_to_byt_array(passwd);
    byte[] expanded_passwd_byte = Utils.expand_byt_array(passwd_byte, KEY_SIZE);
    Object key = s.makeKey(expanded_passwd_byte, BLOCK_SIZE);

    //data (flag + modulus + original data + alignment empty bytes (zeros))
    byte[] flag = string_to_byt_array(INITIAL_FLAG);
    Integer modulus = (flag.length + 1 + data.length) % BLOCK_SIZE;
    Byte mod = modulus.byteValue();
    byte[] data_flag_extended = concat_array(flag, mod);
    data_flag_extended = concat_array(data_flag_extended, data);

    if(modulus != 0)
        data_flag_extended = fill_with_zeros(data_flag_extended, data_flag_extended.length + BLOCK_SIZE - modulus);

    //data encrypt (block size) loop
    int pos = 0;
    byte[] out = new byte[data_flag_extended.length];
    while(true)
    {
        s.encrypt(data_flag_extended, pos, out, pos, key, BLOCK_SIZE);

        pos += BLOCK_SIZE;

        if(pos == data_flag_extended.length)
            return out;
    }
}

/**
 * TESTED. WORKS FINE
 * @param data
 * @param passwd
 * @return NULL on password fail
 * @throws java.security.InvalidKeyException
 */
@Override
public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException
{
    if(passwd.length() > KEY_SIZE)
        throw new InvalidKeyException("Password too long");

    Serpent s = new Serpent();

    //passwd (we need key to decrypt)
    byte[] passwd_byte = Utils.string_to_byt_array(passwd);
    byte[] expanded_passwd_byte = Utils.expand_byt_array(passwd_byte, KEY_SIZE);
    Object key = s.makeKey(expanded_passwd_byte, BLOCK_SIZE);

    //data decrypt
    byte[] out = new byte[data.length];
    int pos = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        s.decrypt(data, pos, out, pos, key, BLOCK_SIZE);
        pos += BLOCK_SIZE;
        if(pos == data.length)
            break;
    }

    //flag check & metedata delete (flag and modulus)
    int flag_size = INITIAL_FLAG.length();
    String flag = new String(subarray(out, 0, flag_size));
    if(!flag.equals(INITIAL_FLAG))
        return null;

    //flag check passed
    //now, deletion of metadata
    int modulus = out[flag_size];
    byte[] data_no_metadata = subarray(out, flag_size + 1, out.length - flag_size - 1);

    //now, deletion of zeroes added in order to align with BLOCK_SIZE
    if(modulus == 0)
        return data_no_metadata;

    return subarray(data_no_metadata, 0, data_no_metadata.length - BLOCK_SIZE + modulus);
}        

static void show_cipher_info()
{
    Serpent s = new Serpent();

    w("block sizes:");
    Iterator<Integer> it = s.blockSizes();
    while(it.hasNext())
        w(it.next());

    w("key sizes:");
    it = s.keySizes();
    while(it.hasNext())
        w(it.next());


    /*
    block sizes:
    16

    key sizes:
    16
    24
    32
    */   
}

@Override
public byte[] encrypt(File file, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException {
    boolean check_exists = true;
    boolean exit_on_fail = true;
    check_file(file, check_exists, exit_on_fail);

    byte[] data = read_file(file);
    return encrypt(data, passwd);
}

@Override
public byte[] decrypt(File file, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException {
    boolean check_exists = true;
    boolean exit_on_fail = true;
    check_file(file, check_exists, exit_on_fail);

    byte[] data = read_file(file);
    return decrypt(data, passwd);
}

@Override
public boolean encrypt(File file_in, File file_out, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException {
    boolean check_exists = true;
    boolean exit_on_fail = true;
    check_file(file_in, check_exists, exit_on_fail);

    check_exists = false;
    exit_on_fail = true;
    check_file(file_out, check_exists, exit_on_fail);

    byte[] data = read_file(file_in);
    write_file(file_out, encrypt(data, passwd));
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean decrypt(File file_in, File file_out, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException {
    boolean check_exists = true;
    boolean exit_on_fail = true;
    check_file(file_in, check_exists, exit_on_fail);

    check_exists = false;
    exit_on_fail = true;
    check_file(file_out, check_exists, exit_on_fail);

    byte[] data = read_file(file_in);
    byte[] decrypt = decrypt(data, passwd);
    if(decrypt == null)
        return false;
    write_file(file_out, decrypt);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean decrypt(byte[] data, File file_out, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException {
    boolean check_exists = false;
    boolean exit_on_fail = true;
    check_file(file_out, check_exists, exit_on_fail);

    byte[] decrypt = decrypt(data, passwd);
    if(decrypt == null)
        return false;
    write_file(file_out, decrypt);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean encrypt(byte[] data, File file_out, String passwd) throws InvalidKeyException {
    boolean check_exists = false;
    boolean exit_on_fail = true;
    check_file(file_out, check_exists, exit_on_fail);

    write_file(file_out, encrypt(data, passwd));
    return true;
}

@Override
public int get_block_size() {
    return BLOCK_SIZE;
}
}
```

Utils.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Utils {

public static void w(Object msg)
{
    System.out.println(msg);
}

public static byte[] string_to_byt_array(String txt)
{
    char[] toCharArray = txt.toCharArray();
    byte[] ret = new byte[toCharArray.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < toCharArray.length; i++)
        ret[i] = (byte)toCharArray[i];

    return ret;
}

public static Byte[] string_to_byte_array(String txt)
{
    char[] toCharArray = txt.toCharArray();
    Byte[] ret = new Byte[toCharArray.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < toCharArray.length; i++)
        ret[i] = (byte)toCharArray[i];

    return ret;
}

public static byte[] expand_byt_array(byte[] array, int size)
{
    if(array.length == size)
        return array;
    else if(array.length > size)
        return null;

    byte[] ret = new byte[size];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, ret, 0, array.length);

    return ret;
}

public static byte[] concat_array(byte[] array_a, byte[] array_b)
{
    return concat_array(array_a, array_b, -1, -1, -1, -1);
}

public static byte[] concat_array(byte[] array_a, byte[] array_b,
        int init_a, int length_a, int init_b, int length_b)
{

    if(init_a == -1)
        init_a = 0;
    if(length_a == -1)
        length_a = array_a.length;
    if(init_b == -1)
        init_b = 0;
    if(length_b == -1)
        length_b = array_b.length;

    byte[] ret = new byte[length_a - init_a + length_b - init_b];
    int cont = 0;

    //array a
    for(int i = init_a; i < length_a + init_a; cont++, i++)
        ret[cont] = array_a[i];

    //array b
    for(int i = init_b; i < length_b + init_b; cont++, i++)
        ret[cont] = array_b[i];

    return ret;
}

public static byte[] concat_array(byte[] array_a, byte b)
{
    byte[] array_b = new byte[]{b};
    return concat_array(array_a, array_b);
}

public static <T> T[] concat_array(T[] array_a, T[] array_b)
{
    T[] ret = (T[])new Object[array_a.length + array_b.length];

    //array a
    System.arraycopy(array_a, 0, ret, 0, array_a.length);

    //array b
    for(int index_x = 0, index_y = array_a.length; index_x < array_b.length; index_x++, index_y++)
        ret[index_y] = array_b[index_x];

    return ret;
}

public static <T> T[] concat_array(T[] array_a, T b)
{
    T[] array_b = (T[])new Object[]{b};
    return concat_array(array_a, array_b);
}

public static Byte[] array_byte_conversion(byte[] array)
{
    Byte[] ret = new Byte[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        ret[i] = array[i];

    return ret;
}

public static byte[] array_byt_conversion(Byte[] array)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        ret[i] = array[i];

    return ret;
}

/**
 * NOT TESTED
 * @param <T>
 * @param array
 * @param pos
 * @param length
 * @return 
 */
public static <T> T[] subarray(T[] array, int pos, int length)
{
    if(pos + length > array.length)
        length = pos + length - array.length;

    T[] ret = (T[])new Object[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        ret[i] = array[i + pos];

    return ret;
}

/**
 * NOT TESTED
 * @param array
 * @param pos
 * @param length
 * @return 
 */
public static byte[] subarray(byte[] array, int pos, int length)
{
    //check overflow on right
    if(pos + length > array.length)
        length = pos + length - array.length;

    byte[] ret = new byte[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        ret[i] = array[i + pos];

    return ret;
}

public static byte[] fill_with_zeros(byte[] array, int desired_size)
{
    if(array.length >= desired_size)
        return array;

    byte[] ret = new byte[desired_size];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, ret, 0, array.length);

    return ret;
}

public static boolean compare_byt_array(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    if(a.length != b.length)
        return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] != b[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

   public static boolean check_file(File file, boolean check_exists, boolean exit_on_fail)
   {
   boolean ret = file.exists();
   if(ret != check_exists && exit_on_fail)
   {
       if(ret)
           w("Error. File already exists");
       else
           w("Error. File not found");
       System.exit(0);
   }

   if(check_exists)
       return ret;
   else
       return !ret;
   }

   public static byte[] read_file(File file)
   {
    byte[] ret = new byte[0];

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] read = new byte[1024];    
        int cont;
        while((cont = fis.read(read)) != -1)
            ret = concat_array(ret, read, -1, -1, 0, cont);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return ret;
   }

   public static boolean write_file(File file, byte[] data)
   {
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(data);
        return true;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: So, basically, you're sending some Metadata unencrypted?

Comment: Secure in what sense, and from whom? Your meddling 8 year old sister? Local ruffians? Major organized crime syndicates?

Comment: What's the Metadata?

Comment: this flag is added when encrypting and when decrypting I look for this flag and if i doesn't match, then bad password. My question is about if this method is risky because maybe is much more easier to break the password if anyone knows that fixed flag (source code) and have two or more encrypted files.

Comment: and the flag is inserted with data, and then encrypted all together

Comment: Does the flag contain an actual password (or is just a yes/no kind of thing)?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what parts are actually encrypted and what the flag actually contains and is used for. Is the flag encrypted? Or are you concerned that if you have too "obvious"/fixed of a structure to your messages that that in and of itself will compromise security?

Comment: there is a crypto specific stack exchange: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Seems like your question might be answered here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15402

Comment: I will try to be more precise. For example, I want to encrypt a file containing this text: "table". Also, my tag is always a 6 bytes word ("QWERTY" in this example). My code creates a String containing tag+NUMBER+text_to_encrypt. NUMBER (1 byte so 0 to 255, I use only 0 to 15) is only to know how many bytes of the last 16 bytes block correspond to my file. In this example the String value is "QWERTY(12)table". (NUMBER is flag.length + 1 + data.length) % 16. I use this system because without i cannot be sure decrypted data is correct  ;)

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding this correctly, your concern is whether having a "fixed" structure could increase the risk of a [known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack). A known plaintext attack is when an attacker has access to an example of a "plaintext" (i.e. an unencrypted message) and its accompanying "ciphertext" (i.e. the encrypted text). For some older algorithms, it was possible to discover the keys based on one - or several - of these known plaintexts. This then made it possible to decrypt and read any other message encrypted with the same key.

In fact, the [Enigma machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine) in World War II fell victim to an attack much like what you're describing - reports (e.g. weather reports) tended to follow a fixed, predictable structure, which allowed the Allies to guess at their content in order to get known plaintexts. They would then use the known plaintexts to recover that day's keys and use the keys to decrypt other messages. An officer in Africa was especially helpful in that regards, and would wire back "nothing to report" every day at approximately the same time of day.

Incidentally, for obvious reasons, modern algorithms are designed to be secure against known-plaintext attacks. You'd generally need huge numbers of known plaintexts to be able to successfully recover even a single key.

That being said, modern algorithms are *not* susceptible to this attack. Even if an attacker *does* discover the structure of your messages and is able to "guess at" a few known plaintexts, the attacker would still need a vast number of these in order to be able to recover the key.

Another important property that encryption algorithms have: very small differences in the plaintext will tend to make large differences in the ciphertext. For example, even with the older DES algorithm, changing a single bit could result in changes to up to 31 bits in the ciphertext. This is what's known as the [avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect). This will make it even more difficult to derive useful information because it's very difficult to determine which part of the ciphertext "corresponds" to which part of the plaintext - it's not at all trivial to figure out *why* a particular bit was set the way it was without having access to the original key. There is *no guarantee* that bit 1 of the ciphertext was set the way that it was due to the value of bit 1 of the plaintext, for example - for all an attacker knows, it could've been changed due to a change in bit 10.

As mentioned by @ScottNewson, [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15401/prefixing-data-before-encryption-for-passphrase-confirmation) may also help you.

Consider the following plaintext message:

1001010100110101010101110

which corresponds to following ciphertext:

0110000111100110101000101

Now let's suppose that I change the last bit to 1 in the plaintext:

1001010100110101010101111

This will likely change *multiple* bits in the ciphertext, which may or may not include the last bit, so there's no reason to believe that it'll result in something like

1001010100110101010101110

In fact, it's *extremely unlikely* that it would result in such a change.

**TL;DR** Knowing the structure of your messages won't be especially helpful to a potential attacker.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly the question I has on my mind .I will put here a link to the source code in Java (it includes a GUI) but I think most useful would be the API methods.